# I am having trouble with percentages in a MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

I am mostly having trouble with percentages. Can anyone help me with a simple select statement to help me solve this?

> List the COURSE, TITLE, FEES, and what the FEE would be with a 5% increase from the COURSE table. Do not print any fees that are 0. Order the results by TITLE.

Comment: Please paste your query...

Answer (score 0):

To increase by 5% you can multiply by 1.05:

```
SELECT   course, title, feed, fees * 1.05 AS fees_with_increase
FROM     course
WHERE    fees != 0
ORDER BY title ASC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really close, but now it works perfect! I was missing the where clause and also added parenthesis to the numbers, thanks again!